# Cloning chacaters in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do something like this in Unity - https://youtu.be/uLZvNNW_Xoc , where when I go through the checkpoint, I get the exact mathematical result (clones of the character) of the same character who passed it.

I tried to clone them manually so that I knew how the animation and the walk would be, but when I turned on the game, it all shattered, the characters started to run around and bounced off each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can Clone GameObjects with `GameObject.Instantiate()`

More details here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

You can try setting a specific position for each cloned GameObject, it sounds like u are cloning them too close to each other.

Here's a little example of what I mean:

```
GameObject characterToClone = GameObject.Find("NameOfYourCharacterGameObject");

for(int i = 0; i < amountOfClonesNeeded; i++)
{
    Vector3 newPosition = characterToClone.transform.position + new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
    characterToClone = GameObject.Instantiate(characterToClone, newPosition, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Like this you can Clone your Character multiple times where every new Clone should be 10 units appart from the previos one! You probably have to adjust the offset yourself though to make it fit perfectly for your game.
I hope I was able to help you!